# select from table with result of another sql

Tags: php, sql, select

Is it possible?

tag_table :

```
tag        postid
aa          22  
bb          26  
cc          28
```

post_table :

```
id          content
26            abc  
28            cdf  
22            fds
```

and I wanna select from post_table with result of search in tag_table

my script :
first

```
SELECT postid FROM `tag_table` WHERE `tag` LIKE '%aa%'
```

and put results in array then run a sql again

```
foreach ($postids as $key => $post_id) {
$sql .= "`id` = $post_id or";
}
```

and $sql is

```
SELECT * FROM `post_table` WHERE `id` = 22     or etc
```

**and I wanna do it with one sql code** 
is it possible ?

Answer (score 8):

You can use a subquery and `IN` statement like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `post_table` 
WHERE `id` IN (SELECT `postid`
               FROM `tag_table`
               WHERE `tag` LIKE '%aa%')
```

Comment: +1 for being the right answer for modern hardware. If you're using really old/slow stuff however, it's sometimes better to do it programatically: do the SELECT, and then run individual, keyed, queries out of an iterator. Sounds weird, but it'll give you a dramatic performance increase on legacy hardware.